# A = {x/x^2+1 : x belongs to reals } Show that A is a subset of [-1/2, 1/2]

Tags: logic

I am really stuck with this assignment and have very little idea on how to proceed. I think using derivative is not allowed. How should I proceed, could anyone give any tips?

I've thought something like.

If $x>0$
$$
x^2+1 > x \geq 1
$$
But this is really all I got, I've tried changing the form of the expression but nothing really. I would be grateful for tips!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will prove that
$$
\left| \frac{x}{x^2+1}\right|\le\frac{1}{2}
$$
for every real number $x$. Square both sides of the inequality then we get
$$
\frac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^2}\le\frac{1}{4}.
$$
In fact, these two inequalities are equivalent, and last inequality is easy to prove: it is equivalent to $0\le (x^2-1)^2$.

Comment: I don't really get how that shows that the largest number the expression can give is 1/2 and the smallest -1/2. Could you open it up some more?

Comment: @SamuliLehtonen Let $a$ be a positive real number then $|x|\le a$ if and only if $-a\le x\le a$.

Comment: In fact, the range of $f(x)=x/(1+x^2)$ is $[-1/2,1/2]$. But you want to show that the range of $f$ is a subset of $[-1/2,1/2]$. So we only find the upper bound and lower bound of the range.

Comment: Yeah I got it now, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $x^2 +1 - 2x = (x-1)^2 \geq 0$, and $x^2+1 + 2x = (x+1)^2 \geq 0$

Answer (score 0):

$$\left|\dfrac{x^2+1}{x}\right| = \dfrac{|x|^2+1}{|x|} = |x|+\frac1{|x|}\ge 2\sqrt{|x|\frac1{|x|}}.$$